# node-webkit How to call a function in another window?

Tags: javascript, windows, node.js, node-webkit

I have created a new window with this piece of code and tried to send some data but the function is not called, maybe I'm doing it wrong?

script.js on index.html

```
var path = require('path');
element.onclick = function(){
    var win = gui.Window.get(window.open('listdir.html'));
    var location = path.resolve(process.cwd(),'fontsFolder');
    win.eval(null, 'listdir("'+location+'")'); //Is there a node function to parse '\'?
};
```

listdir.js on listdir.html

```
function listdir(directory){
    alert("directory "+directory); //never called
}
```

Error:

```
ReferenceError: listdir is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:1
    at Window.init.Window.eval (window_bindings.js:486:16)
    at HTMLLIElement.element.onclick (file:///C:/../AppData/Local/Temp/nw3528_1882/js/script.js:29:12)
```

Comment: You could append your parameters to the URL, like a GET request: `listdir.html?param1=value1&param2=value2`

Comment: Yes I can certainly do so, I was just expecting there was a more dynamic way.

Comment: You can use the 'global' variable to share anything, including functions, between windows. https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit/wiki/Transfer-objects-between-window-and-node

Answer (score 1):

Okay, this might not be the *right* answer for the question "How to call a function in another window", but an answer for your initial problem "How to send parameters to new window" (before editing the title).

As I'm an enthusiast of the new storage objects in HTML5, I would synchronize the windows over `sessionStorage` (so all passed parameters will survive the current new window lifetime, but not afterwards).

My working solution:

index.html (the initial window)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    Test <a href="">Click</a>

    <script src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var mySharedObj = {
            'one': 1,
            'two': 2,
            'three': 3
        };

        // node-webkit specific
        var gui = require('nw.gui');

        $('a').click(function() {
            var win = gui.Window.get(window.open('index2.html'));
            win.eval(null, 'sessionStorage.setItem(\'mySharedJSON\', \''+JSON.stringify(mySharedObj)+'\');');
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

index2.html (the new window that will be opened via `window.open` call:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    Test 2: 

    <script src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script> 
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            // Process sharedObj when DOM is loaded
            var mySharedObj = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('mySharedJSON'));

            // Now you can do anything with mySharedObj

            console.log(mySharedObj);
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

So, how does it work? `window.eval` (see [documentation](https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit/wiki/Window#windowevalframe-script) here) needs source code of scripts, that may be run in the context of the newly created window. I guess, your first try didn't work, as the script will be executed just in the moment the window is created, thus the DOM is not yet parsed and no JavaScript functions are available at that moment. So there are only the basic functions available (the `window` object). So we're passing in a function that will store a serialized JSON in the window.sessionStorage. That way, you are able to access it from all functions in the new window.

Again: This is not the correct answer for general usage, but it might fit for your problem.

Comment: You are right, Window.eval is called before DOM has fully loaded, I listened to document-end event and everything works perfect now, thank you :)